# Render function outputs different file in two environments

Tags: r, r-markdown

My local environment is outputting a slightly different file than my testing environment and I'm struggling to understand why. Here's my render function:

```
report_filename <- file.path('./R', 'render_data.rmd')
output_dir <- "output"
output <- file.path("..",output_dir)
render(report_filename,
       output_yaml = "./R/_output.yaml", 
       output_dir = output_dir,
       params = list(output_dir = output)
       )
```

I've checked to make sure the file `_output.yaml` file is the same in both environments. What are some other settings that affect `render`? The output file in my testing environment is getting created in the same HTML output file but has some extra lines that are throwing errors when I refer to the file as the body in `mailR`'s send.mail.

The difference is mostly that the output file in my testing environment includes a few scripts, I think Javascript scripts near the top of the file. How do I remove them? I've been playing around with the yaml file but am having difficulty editing that as well. Here's what the yaml config file looks like:

```
---
output:
    rmarkdown::html_vignette
---
```

The main difference is that the testing environment's output file includes these lines:

```
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,JChkb2N1bWVudCkucmVhZHkoZnVuY3Rpb24oKXsKICAgIGlmICh0eXBlb2YgJCgnW2RhdGEtdG9nZ2xlPSJ0b29sdGlwIl0nKS50b29sdGlwID09PSAnZnVuY3Rpb24nKSB7CiAgICAgICAgJCgnW2RhdGEtdG9nZ2xlPSJ0b29sdGlwIl0nKS50b29sdGlwKCk7CiAgICB9CiAgICBpZiAoJCgnW2RhdGEtdG9nZ2xlPSJwb3BvdmVyIl0nKS5wb3BvdmVyID09PSAnZnVuY3Rpb24nKSB7CiAgICAgICAgJCgnW2RhdGEtdG9nZ2xlPSJwb3BvdmVyIl0nKS5wb3BvdmVyKCk7CiAgICB9Cn0pOwo="></script>


<link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8,body%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23fff%3B%0Amargin%3A%201em%20auto%3B%0Amax%2Dwidth%3A%20700px%3B%0Aoverflow%3A%20visible%3B%0Apadding%2Dleft%3A%202em%3B%0Apadding%2Dright%3A%202em%3B%0Afont%2Dfamily%3A%20%22Open%20Sans%22%2C%20%22Helvetica%20Neue%22%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Arial%2C%20sans%2Dserif%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2014px%3B%0Aline%2Dheight%3A%201%2E35%3B%0A%7D%0A%23TOC%20%7B%0Aclear%3A%20both%3B%0Amargin%3A%200%200%2010px%2010px%3B%0Apadding%3A%204px%3B%0Awidth%3A%20400px%3B%0Aborder%3A%201px%20solid%20%23CCCCCC%3B%0Aborder%2Dradius%3A%205px%3B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23f6f6f6%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2013px%3B%0Aline%2Dheight%3A%201%2E3%3B%0A%7D%0A%23TOC%20%2Etoctitle%20%7B%0Afont%2Dweight%3A%20bold%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2015px%3B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%205px%3B%0A%7D%0A%23TOC%20ul%20%7B%0Apadding%2Dleft%3A%2040px%3B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%20%2D1%2E5em%3B%0Amargin%2Dtop%3A%205px%3B%0Amargin%2Dbottom%3A%205px%3B%0A%7D%0A%23TOC%20ul%20ul%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%20%2D2em%3B%0A%7D%0A%23TOC%20li%20%7B%0Aline%2Dheight%3A%2016px%3B%0A%7D%0Atable%20%7B%0Amargin%3A%201em%20auto%3B%0Aborder%2Dwidth%3A%201px%3B%0Aborder%2Dcolor%3A%20%23DDDDDD%3B%0Aborder%2Dstyle%3A%20outset%3B%0Aborder%2Dcollapse%3A%20collapse%3B%0A%7D%0Atable%20th%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dwidth%3A%202px%3B%0Apadding%3A%205px%3B%0Aborder%2Dstyle%3A%20inset%3B%0A%7D%0Atable%20td%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dwidth%3A%201px%3B%0Aborder%2Dstyle%3A%20inset%3B%0Aline%2Dheight%3A%2018px%3B%0Apadding%3A%205px%205px%3B%0A%7D%0Atable%2C%20table%20th%2C%20table%20td%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dleft%2Dstyle%3A%20none%3B%0Aborder%2Dright%2Dstyle%3A%20none%3B%0A%7D%0Atable%20thead%2C%20table%20tr%2Eeven%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0A%7D%0Ap%20%7B%0Amargin%3A%200%2E5em%200%3B%0A%7D%0Ablockquote%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23f6f6f6%3B%0Apadding%3A%200%2E25em%200%2E75em%3B%0A%7D%0Ahr%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dstyle%3A%20solid%3B%0Aborder%3A%20none%3B%0Aborder%2Dtop%3A%201px%20solid%20%23777%3B%0Amargin%3A%2028px%200%3B%0A%7D%0Adl%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%200%3B%0A%7D%0Adl%20dd%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dbottom%3A%2013px%3B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%2013px%3B%0A%7D%0Adl%20dt%20%7B%0Afont%2Dweight%3A%20bold%3B%0A%7D%0Aul%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dtop%3A%200%3B%0A%7D%0Aul%20li%20%7B%0Alist%2Dstyle%3A%20circle%20outside%3B%0A%7D%0Aul%20ul%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dbottom%3A%200%3B%0A%7D%0Apre%2C%20code%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0Aborder%2Dradius%3A%203px%3B%0Acolor%3A%20%23333%3B%0Awhite%2Dspace%3A%20pre%2Dwrap%3B%20%0A%7D%0Apre%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dradius%3A%203px%3B%0Amargin%3A%205px%200px%2010px%200px%3B%0Apadding%3A%2010px%3B%0A%7D%0Apre%3Anot%28%5Bclass%5D%29%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0A%7D%0Acode%20%7B%0Afont%2Dfamily%3A%20Consolas%2C%20Monaco%2C%20%27Courier%20New%27%2C%20monospace%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2085%25%3B%0A%7D%0Ap%20%3E%20code%2C%20li%20%3E%20code%20%7B%0Apadding%3A%202px%200px%3B%0A%7D%0Adiv%2Efigure%20%7B%0Atext%2Dalign%3A%20center%3B%0A%7D%0Aimg%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23FFFFFF%3B%0Apadding%3A%202px%3B%0Aborder%3A%201px%20solid%20%23DDDDDD%3B%0Aborder%2Dradius%3A%203px%3B%0Aborder%3A%201px%20solid%20%23CCCCCC%3B%0Amargin%3A%200%205px%3B%0A%7D%0Ah1%20%7B%0Amargin%2Dtop%3A%200%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2035px%3B%0Aline%2Dheight%3A%2040px%3B%0A%7D%0Ah2%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dbottom%3A%204px%20solid%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0Apadding%2Dtop%3A%2010px%3B%0Apadding%2Dbottom%3A%202px%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%20145%25%3B%0A%7D%0Ah3%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dbottom%3A%202px%20solid%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0Apadding%2Dtop%3A%2010px%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%20120%25%3B%0A%7D%0Ah4%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dbottom%3A%201px%20solid%20%23f7f7f7%3B%0Amargin%2Dleft%3A%208px%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%20105%25%3B%0A%7D%0Ah5%2C%20h6%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dbottom%3A%201px%20solid%20%23ccc%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%20105%25%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%20%230033dd%3B%0Atext%2Ddecoration%3A%20none%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%3Ahover%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%20%236666ff%3B%20%7D%0Aa%3Avisited%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%20%23800080%3B%20%7D%0Aa%3Avisited%3Ahover%20%7B%0Acolor%3A%20%23BB00BB%3B%20%7D%0Aa%5Bhref%5E%3D%22http%3A%22%5D%20%7B%0Atext%2Ddecoration%3A%20underline%3B%20%7D%0Aa%5Bhref%5E%3D%22https%3A%22%5D%20%7B%0Atext%2Ddecoration%3A%20underline%3B%20%7D%0A%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Ekw%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23555%3B%20font%2Dweight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Edt%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23902000%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Edv%20%7B%20color%3A%20%2340a070%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Ebn%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23d14%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Efl%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23d14%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Ech%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23d14%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Est%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23d14%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Eco%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23888888%3B%20font%2Dstyle%3A%20italic%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Eot%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23007020%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Eal%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23ff0000%3B%20font%2Dweight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Efu%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23900%3B%20font%2Dweight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%20%0Acode%20%3E%20span%2Eer%20%7B%20color%3A%20%23a61717%3B%20background%2Dcolor%3A%20%23e3d2d2%3B%20%7D%20%0A" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

whereas the output file in my local environment, where it is slightly smaller and usable in `mailR.send.mail` has this for the script:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    if (typeof $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip === 'function') {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
    if ($('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover === 'function') {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    }
});
</script>
```

I've also tried setting `self_contained: false` in my testing's output.yaml file but that didn't change anything. Here's that `_output.yaml` in testing:

```
---
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
self_contained: false
---
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the differences?

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: are you using different OS for testing and local? Describe the environments.

Comment: Same environment (Windows) for both. I've done my best to make sure the versions for R and its packages are the same in both environments, but can't 100% verify

Comment: I think we need more information, do you have a github repository of your files?

Comment: Figured it out, it was because of pandoc being outdated and another installation being used that caused the odd lines.

Comment: Rstudio cloud can be a useful option for testing different environments and/or conditions.